# Using read_csv with a home-made object as a 'file'

Tags: python, pandas

The `read_csv` doc says that its first parameter can be 'any object with a read() method (such as a file handle or StringIO)'. My question is about how to construct an object that will work in this capacity.

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = 'plain.txt'

class FileWrap:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.file = open(path)
    def read(self):
        return self.file.readline().rstrip()

filewrap = FileWrap(file_name)

while True:
    line = filewrap.read()
    if not line:
        break
    print (line)

df = pd.read_csv(FileWrap(file_name), header=None)
print (df)
```

The output from this script is this.

The first three lines are simply intended to show that the `FileWrap` object's `read` method seems to function as would be expected. The remaining lines serve to show that there's something I don't understand about constructing an object with a `read` method that pandas can use to receive its input a line at a time. What does a `read` have to do to make pandas happy?

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 20, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(FileWrap(file_name), header=None)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 645, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 388, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 729, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 922, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1389, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 535, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:6077)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 797, in pandas.parser.TextReader._get_header (pandas\parser.c:9878)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 909, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:11257)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 2008, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:26804)
TypeError: raise: exception class must be a subclass of BaseException
```

Comment: What happens when you remove/comment out the initial "filewrap =..." and the "while" block? It may be that the file is locked up since it doesn't seem like filewrap.file is closed anywhere.

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you're wrapping it to begin with? What happens when you just hand read_csv an open file to read?

Comment: I agree. You should be able to just use read_csv() directly on 'plain.txt', and (if needed) defining 'sep', 'skiprows', 'header', etc...

Comment: No, you're right, there's no reason for that particular file. But I have a situation in mind where I want to do some pre-processing prior to input to pandas. I didn't want to get into that and, beyond that, didn't want anyone worrying that there might be something peculiar about the input that might confuse pandas.

Comment: @DonRowe: When I removed those lines the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when pandas call check `is_file_like` it invalidate does object has `read` and `__iter__` methods, [is_file_like](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/dtypes/inference.py#L141), so you can try:

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = 'plain.txt'

class FileWrap:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.file = open(path)
    def __iter__(self):
        self.file.readline().rstrip()
    def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.file.read()

df = pd.read_csv(FileWrap(file_name), header=None)
print (df)
```

Comment: Well worth reporting to the developers.

Comment: AAMOF, definition of the `__iter__` method seems unnecessary.

Comment: sorry but i don't know details to discuss.

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for your help.